# How can I open ~/Desktop if I click on "Open in terminal" from the Desktop?

Tags: unity, nautilus, 16.10

**Scenario:**

1. I am on my Desktop.
2. I perform a right mouse click and select "Open in terminal".
3. I envision this to open the terminal in `~/Desktop` and not my home folder.

**System:**

- Ubuntu 16.10
- Unity
- Nautilus

Comment: Isn't it really much faster to Ctrl-T into a new terminal and then $cd Desktop? You can probably even tab-complete after writing Des

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick & easy one coincidentally, since I only needed to change a script I already had a bit :).

The script assumes you have at least one item on your desktop though.

#### How to set up

1. Create, if it doesn't exist yet, the directory `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `terminal_here2` (no extension), and ***make it executable***
3. Log out and back in.

Now right-click on *any* file on your desktop, choose <kbd>Scripts</kbd> --> <kbd>open_terminal2</kbd>:

[image]

and a terminal window will open in the desktop's directory ("Bureaublad" in my case)

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

def replace(path):
    for c in [("%23", "#"), ("%5D", "]"), ("%5E", "^"),
              ("file://", ""), ("%20", " ")]:
        path = path.replace(c[0], c[1])
    return path

# get the current path
current = replace(os.getenv("NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI")) 
# raise the found terminal window
os.chdir(os.path.realpath(current))
subprocess.Popen("gnome-terminal")
```

Comment: You should probably use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) instead of manually replacing %-encoded characters

Comment: Thank you! There is no way to use the already existing "Open in terminal" context menu entry?

Comment: @orschiro I am afraid that is hard-coded in nautilus. Obviously the desktop is not classified as a "normal" window in nautilus, although `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI` shows the correct directory.

Comment: Do you think it is worth filing a feature request for it? It would be consistent that this function would work as expected.

Comment: @orschiro It makes totally sense to me. Actually I was surprised it didn't already work like that.

Comment: Added the bug report to my question above.

Comment: Good point. Removed. :-)

Comment: There's no need to keep the Python process running just to wait for `gnome-terminal` to terminate and then terminate itself. Instead you can call `os.execlp("gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal")` to replace the Python process with `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster wow, I owe you again, this is a major typo. I had `subprocess.Popen()` in mind, which alse terminates the script. Will edit. Thanks *a lot*!

Answer (score 8):

#### Script-less solution

1. Open Nautiuls in your home folder.
2. In your home folder, right click on `Desktop`, click `Make link`. You will be presented with `Link to Desktop` file.
3. Place link on your Desktop. Now whenever you right click on it, and select `Open in Terminal` it will open terminal with current working directory set as desktop.

Comment: This is a clever workaround!

Comment: @orschiro Thanks, and it's fast ,too. Takes less than a minute to set up .